# Как в KDE сделать чтобы на экране входа всегда была английская раскладка?

Tags: linux, kde

Имеется Arch Linux с установленной KDE последней версии — 5.10.0. В качестве менеджера входа в систему используется SDDM. Имеется ровно две раскладки — русская и английская. На экране входа будет выбрана последняя использованная раскладка. Как изменить это, чтобы независимо от последней использованной раскладки на экране входа всегда была английская раскладка? Последовательность действий, иллюстрирующая проблему:

1. Включаю компьютер, появляется экран входа, раскладка клавиатуры ­— английская (это хорошо)
2. Вхожу в систему, изменяю раскладку клавиатуры на русскую
3. Блокирую экран с помощью <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, либо закрываю и открываю крышку ноутбука
4. В обоих случаях появляется экран входа с русской раскладкой клавиатуры (это плохо)

Проблема в том, что пароль состоит из английских символов, и каждый раз при входе мне приходится смотреть, какая сейчас раскладка и менять её, если она русская.

Comment: нелишне будет уточнить, какая именно программа используется в качестве «greeter-а». kdm?

Comment: Да, стоит уточнить. Используется SDDM

Comment: проверьте, выполняется ли [displaycommand](https://www.mankier.com/5/sddm.conf) каждый раз при показе диалога для выбора пользователя. если да, то можно попробовать что-нибудь «намутить» с раскладками. если нет, то стоит поискать что-нибудь, выполняющееся при logout внутри kde.

Comment: Проверил, не выполняется. Про logout отличный совет, сейчас поищу.

Comment: что-то я торможу. `/etc/X11/Xreset.d/` надо использовать. а для переключения взять что-нибудь из [пункта 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/442182/178576)

Comment: У меня в `/etc/X11/` такой папки нету, я её создал, и в ней создал `sh` файл, но что-то он никогда не вызывается. В `/etc/X11/` есть папки `xinit` и `xorg.conf.d`, там тоже создал файлы, они вызываются при включении компьютера и при `logout`, а при блокировки экрана (`Ctrl+Alt+L` либо закрытие крышки ноутбука) не вызываются.

Comment: скрипты из этого каталога вызываются скриптом `/etc/X11/Xreset`. если у вас его нет, то попробуйте его и использовать: каталог в этом случае и не нуже. надо только биты исполнимости добавить. впрочем, возможно, запуск этого скрипта — debian- (и наследники-) специфично. тогда придётся продолжить поиски — может быть есть что-то «родное» в kde.

Answer (score 4):

Я тоже задавался [этим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450037/ubuntu-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-ctrlaltl).

**Вариант 1** (проверка по наличию процесса lockscreen)

Создал скрипт

`$ cat ~/scripts/enru.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
CHKSTR=`ps aux| grep -v grep | grep lockscreen`
if  [[ $CHKSTR == *lockscreen* ]]; then
    kbd=`setxkbmap -print | sed -n 's#xkb_symbols[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*$#\1#p' | awk -F+ '{print $2}'`
    if [[ $kbd == ru ]]; then
        xdotool key 'alt+shift'
    fi
fi
```

Добавил в crontab от имени пользователя строку

`$crontab -u USERNAME -e`

```
*  *  *  *  *  DISPLAY=:0 bash ~/scripts/enru.sh >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Скрипт каждую минуту проверяет, запущен ли процесс `usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service --lockscreen-mode` и, при его наличии, запускает проверку и изменение раскладки клавиатуры.

**Вариант 2** (запуск при нажатии Ctrl+Alt+L)

1. Создал скрипт

   `$ cat ~/scripts/enru2.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   gnome-screensaver-command --lock && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
   # current 0 говорит о том, что нужно включить дефолтную раскладку en_EN. current 1, соответственно, ru_RU
   ```
2. Проверяем, есть ли у нас дополнительные комбинации клавиш, которые мы уже используем:

   ```
   $ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings
   ```

   `['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/']`

   `custom0` говорит о том, что одна комбинация уже добавлена, поэтому надо добавить следующую - `custom1`:

   ```
   $ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/']"
   ```

   Если же вы добавляете свою первую комбинацию клавиш, то выполните команду

   ```
   $ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/']"
   ```
3. Отключаем хоткеи для системного lockscreen'а:

   ```
   $ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screensaver ''
   ```
4. Задаём имя нашему хоткею:

   ```
   $ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ name 'Lockscreen'
   ```
5. Указываем, какую команду надо выполнять:

   ```
   $ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ command "/home/$USER/scripts/enru2.sh"
   ```
6. Задаём комбинацию клавиш для запуска блокировки экрана:

   ```
   $ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ binding '<Ctrl><Alt>l'
   ```

Comment: команда для «определения» раскладки [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440633/178576) взята? в kde это не должно сработать — надеюсь, там нет тех же костылей (см. пункт 2 из [моего ответа там же](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/442182/178576)). для gnome попробуйте вот это предложение: https://askubuntu.com/a/414041/416190 (у меня никаких de под рукой нет, проверить не могу).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, команду брал скорее всего из того вопроса. По поводу другого решения отпишусь позже, когда проверю. Спасибо.

Comment: @zombic, спасибо за ответ! Вариант проверять наличие экрана входа раз в минуту не очень подходит — я неточно описал вопрос — в реальности я нажимаю не `Ctr+Alt+L`, а закрываю крышку ноутбука, а потом открываю, соответственно нужно будет проверять хотя бы раз в секунду, а это для не очень мощного ноутбука не очень хороший вариант.

Comment: @Дмитрий, *в реальности я нажимаю не Ctr+Alt+L, а закрываю крышку ноутбука, а потом открываю* — ох, не зря меня смущало это ctrl+alt **+L**, которое, по логике, означает **L**ock. так вы не завершаете сеанс, а всего лишь блокируете. естественно, x-сессия у вас всё та же, и раскладка всё та же. и иное поведение было бы просто ошибочным. если вы хотите таки сделать его ошибочным, то вам надо не иксовые/de-шные скрипты искать, а те скрипты, которые выполняются при засыпании/просыпании.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да, действительно, всё именно так. Нашёл [скрипты](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Suspend.2Fresume_service_files), которые выполняются при засыпании, смену раскладки сделал через `xkb-switch`. Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Дмитрий, оформите это, пожалуйста, в виде ответа: наверняка кому-нибудь ещё пригодится.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, это хорошая идея.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, добавил второй вариант с нажатием `Ctr+Alt+L`

Answer (score 4):

Имеются два независимых варианта решения, причём можно использовать оба одновременно.

В обоих вариантах используется программа [`xkb-switch`](https://github.com/ierton/xkb-switch). Была выбрана эта программа, так как она позволяет легко переключить раскладку на английскую (альтернативный способ — [определять раскладку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/326790/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83-bash/442182#442182), и если она русская, эмулировать нажатие комбинации клавиш смены раскладки с помощью `xdotool` — может не сработать). В Arch Linux установить `xkb-switch` можно [из AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xkb-switch/).

1. Первый вариант работает, если вы блокируете сеанс с помощью перехода в [ждущий режим](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC) (то есть, например, при закрытии и последующем открытии крышки ноутбука). Заключается он в [написании скрипта](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Suspend.2Fresume_service_files), который будет выполняться непосредственно перед переходом компьютера в ждущий режим. Для [systemd](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) скрипт может выглядеть следующим образом:

   ```
   # /etc/systemd/system/suspend@.service

   [Unit]
   Description=Change keyboard layout to english immediately before suspend
   Before=sleep.target

   [Service]
   User=%I
   Type=simple
   Environment=DISPLAY=:0
   ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/xkb-switch -s us

   [Install]
   WantedBy=sleep.target
   ```

   Чтобы скрипт заработал, нужно выполнить следующую команду:

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable suspend@имя_вашего_пользователя.service
   ```
2. Второй вариант работает, если вы блокируете сеанс, но не выключаете компьютер (так происходит, например, при нажатии <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>). Заключается он в написании скрипта, который будет выполняться каждые несколько десятков секунд (например, каждую минуту). Этот скрипт будет проверять, заблокирован ли сеанс (например, проверив, существует ли процесс с именем, содержащим `lockscreen`),  и если заблокирован, то менять раскладку на английскую. [Подробное описание второго варианта для Ubuntu](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/674558/227016).

Answer (score 1):

Можно подменить исполняемый файл блокировщика (в Kubuntu с KDE Plasma это файл kscreenlocker_greet) на скрипт, выполняющий проверку раскладки и переключение на нужный язык при необходимости. Исходный исполняемый файл переименовывается и запускается в последней строке скрипта. В моем случае скрипт выглядит так:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# You need to install xkb-switch 
# and rename original "kscreenlocker_greet" to "kscreenlocker_greet_orig"
kbd=`xset -q | grep LED | awk '{print $10}' | cut -c 5`
echo $kbd
if [ $kbd = 1 ]; then
xkb-switch -n
fi
sleep .5
exec /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kscreenlocker_greet_orig "$@"
exit
```

Конечно, xkb-switch должен [быть установлен](https://launchpad.net/%7Eatareao/+archive/ubuntu/atareao/+packages?field.name_filter=xkb-switch&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=).